# Does regular Stop Leak fluid work in Asian vehicles such as ES 300?

Tags: power-steering, leak, lexus, compatibility

For my 1997 Lexus ES300, the power steering fluid I'm using is [Prestone AS269](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007PZNNWK) which is specifically marked as suitable for Asian manufactured vehicles  including Lexus.

Prestone also sells [AS263 Power Steering Fluid](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004AHDBLE) with Stop Leak that says its *developed for use in ... most foreign cars*. There is also the additive [Bar's Stop Leak concentrate](http://www.autozone.com/brake-and-power-steering-fluid-additives/power-steering-fluid-and-additive/bar-s-power-steering-stop-leak/570158_0_0) that doesn't mention compatible vehicles.

Can either of these be used in my car? If so, how can I estimate my chances of success and avoid complications? I'm also not sure if these solutions have zero side effect or they're similar to the tire patching stuff that fills up tubes and makes actual repair harder later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "stop leak" is a temporary fix - do the job properly and repair the leak.

The Bar's Stop Leak - is that the one for the cooling system ? make sure you use the correct one.

That being said, I have used stop leak before but only as a temporary solution before I repaired the real problem.

Comment: If it is a fix at all. I have had two power steering leaks, none of which were affected at all by the power steering stop leak fluid.

Comment: "temporary" meant it got me home, not that it lasted 2 days or longer.... Some treat it as a permanent fix.